# How to insert data array in database with its respective data array using Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Question model

```
public function answer() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Answer');
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <label>{{$question->question}}</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="question_ids[]" value="{{$question->id}}">
    <textarea name="answers[]"></textarea>           
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
foreach($request->input('question_ids') as $id) {
    foreach($request->input('answer') as $ans) {
        $answer = new Answer;
        $question = Question::find($id);
        $answer->answer = $ans;
        $question->answer()->save($answer);
    }
}
```

I want to insert questions with its respective answers but it is inserting answers to the same question. Please anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd rethink how you're creating the form. You're actually inputting all of the answers into all of the questions. Since the question id isn't from user-input, I'd suggest doing `answers[{{$question->id}}]` so the answer key will always be the value of the question ID, which you can then pull back out properly in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Problem is solved now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the textarea answer field as array consist of key filled with question id.

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <label>{{$question->question}}</label>
    <textarea name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"></textarea>           
@endforeach
```

And the controller. Slightly edited to my preference.

```
foreach ($request->input('answers') as $questionId => $value) {
    if ($question = Question::find($questionId)) {
        $answer = new Answer;
        $answer->answer = $value;
        $answer->question_id = $questionId;
        $answer->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as from @Chay22, just a bit shorter.

```
foreach ($request->input('answers') as $questionId => $value) {
    if ($question = Question::find($questionId)) {
        $question->answer()->save(
             new Answer(['answer' => $value])
        );
    }
}
```

Take care that you have `answer` in the `fillable` array of `Answer` model.